# How to prevent width miscalculation when vertical scrollbar appears or disappears?

Tags: javascript, css, grid, scrollbar, width

I have made a website with a tree explorer living in a sidebar. Currently there is a miscalculation of the explorer's width when I toggle the subtrees. The problem occurs on Chrome 111.0.5563.64 for Ubuntu Desktop and is reproduced in the code snippet below.

```js
var [leftEl, rightEl] = (
  document.getElementById("grid")
).children;

var tree = `\
node /1
  node /1/1
  node /1/2
  node /1/3
    node /1/3/1
    node /1/3/2
    node /1/3/3
node /2
  node /2/1
  node /2/2
  node /2/3
`;

leftEl.addEventListener("click", function({ target }) {
  if (target !== this) if (target.tagName === "DIV") {
    var liEl = target.parentNode;
    var classAttr = liEl.getAttribute("class");
    if (classAttr === "unfolded") {
      liEl.removeAttribute("class");
    } else if (classAttr !== "leaf") {
      liEl.setAttribute("class", "unfolded");
    }
  }
});

leftEl.addEventListener("mouseover", function({ target }) {
  if (target !== this) if (target.tagName === "DIV") {
    target.setAttribute("class", "highlighted");
    rightEl.textContent = target.textContent;
  }
});

leftEl.addEventListener("mouseout", function({ target }) {
  if (target !== this) if (target.tagName === "DIV") {
    target.removeAttribute("class");
  }
});

leftEl.innerHTML = "<ul>" + (
  tree.split("\n").slice(0, -1)
  // string to nested objects
. reduce(function (stack, line) {
    var i = line.search(/[^ ]/);
    var depth = i / 2;
    if (depth + 1 > stack.length) {
      var [tree] = stack.slice(-1);
      tree = tree.children.slice(-1)[0];
      tree.children = [];
      stack.push(tree);
    } else {
      stack = stack.slice(0, depth + 1);
      var [tree] = stack.slice(-1);
    }
    tree.children.push(
      { name : line.slice(i) }
    );
    return stack;
  }, [{ children : [] }])[0]
  // nested objects to HTML
. children.reduce(function nodeToHtml (
    [html, depth], { name, children }
  ) {
    children = !children ? "" : "<ul>" + (
      children.reduce(nodeToHtml, ["", depth + 1])[0]
    ) + "</ul>";
    return [html + (
      "<li" + (children ? "" : ' class="leaf"') + ">"
    +   `<div style="padding-left:${.5 + depth}em">${name}</div>`
    +   children
    + "</li>"
    ), depth];
  }, ["", 0])[0]
) + "</ul>";
```

```css
#grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / auto 1fr;
}

#grid > div:first-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background: yellow;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

#grid > div:last-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  background: cyan;
  padding: .25em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

li div {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 10px solid lime;
}

li div.highlighted {
  background: cyan;
}

li div::before {
  content: "▸\a0\a0";
}

li.unfolded > div::before {
  content: "▾\a0\a0";
}

li.leaf div::before {
  visibility: hidden;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

li.unfolded > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div>
    <!-- Example -- >
    <ul>
      <li class="leaf">
        <div class="highlighted">node /1</div>
      </li>
      <li class="unfolded">
        <div>node /2</div>
        <ul>
          <li class="leaf">
            <div>node /2/1</div>
          </li>
          <li class="leaf">
            <div>node /2/2</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- -->
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, we have two `div` elements side by side in a grid layout.

[image]

The yellow `div` element (on the left) is the tree explorer. This `div` element must be vertically scrollable because its height is fixed and its content can be arbitrarily long.

The blue `div` element (on the right) grows horizontally according to the `fr` unit. The content of this `div` element is updated when the mouse cursor hovers over a node in the tree explorer.

The miscalculation of the explorer's width appears when its scollbar appears or disappears. Steps to reproduce the bug:

1. unfold "node /1"

   [image]

   - the scrollbar of the yellow `div` element appears
   - the green border reveals a text overflow
2. move cursor to "node /1/1"

   [image]

   - the content of the blue `div` element is updated
   - the text overflow disappears
3. fold "node /1"

   [image]

   - the scrollbar of the yellow `div` element disappears
   - the green border reveals a phantom content
4. move cursor to "node /2"

   [image]

   - the content of the blue `div` element is updated
   - the phantom content disappears

I suspect the algorithm computing the various widths to execute the following sequence of computations for all of the above steps:

1. Update the width of the yellow `div` element.

   ```
   // At this point, `content width` should be seen
   // from the perspective of the container, that is,
   // `content width` = `max-content` (the CSS value).
   if scrollbar visible then
     container width = content width + scrollbar width
   else
     container width = content width
   end if
   ```
2. Update the scrollbar of the yellow `div` element.

   ```
   if content height > container height then
     show scrollbar
   else
     hide scrollbar
   end if
   ```
3. Update the width of the content of the yellow `div` element.

   ```
   if scrollbar visible then
     content width = container width - scrollbar width
   else
     content width = container width
   end if
   ```

Based on this assumption (I am currently looking for resources on the web to check if I'm right or wrong), here is my next guess:

- At step 1 and step 3, the scrollbar is toggled at computation 2, meaning that the final state of the scrollbar is not available for computation 1, hence the bug.
- At step 2 and step 4, the scrollbar remains unchanged at computation 2, meaning that the final state of the scrollbar is available for computation 1, hence the fix.

The only solution I can think of so far is to mimic step 2 and step 4, updating the blue `div` element as soon as the bug appears (on click):

```
19 | leftEl.addEventListener("click", function({ target }) {
18 |   if (target !== this) if (target.tagName === "DIV") {
   …
28 |     var text = rightEl.textContent;
29 |     rightEl.textContent = "";
30 |     setTimeout(function () {
31 |       rightEl.textContent = text;
32 |     }, 0);
33 |   }
34 | });
```

As I understand it, the timer (L30-L32) pushes the second assignment (L31) to [the task queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide#tasks_vs._microtasks), giving the browser a chance to print the empty content (L29), which is supposed to trigger the sequence of computations above.

This solution works, but it comes with a visual glitch and one extra computation, as we force two [reflows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Reflow) (L29 and L31) when only one is required. Moreover, generaly speaking, relying on the task queue sounds like a bad idea, as it makes programs harder to predict.

Is there a better way to prevent this bug (preferably a well known fix in pure CSS or HTML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Melik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75831818/11446880) led me to an interesting solution:

```
19 | leftEl.addEventListener("click", function({ target }) {
20 |   if (target !== this) if (target.tagName === "DIV") {
   …
28 |     if (this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight) {
29 |       this.style.overflowY = "scroll";
30 |     } else {
31 |       this.style.overflowY = "hidden";
32 |     }
33 |   }
34 | });
```

The idea is to predict and set the state of the scrollbar before the next reflow, in order to make it available for computation. It turns out that `scrollHeight` is already updated at this point (check console log). I was not aware of that, hence the timer in my first attempt.

```js
var [leftEl, rightEl] = (
  document.getElementById("grid")
).children;

var tree = `\
node /1
  node /1/1
  node /1/2
  node /1/3
    node /1/3/1
    node /1/3/2
    node /1/3/3
node /2
  node /2/1
  node /2/2
  node /2/3
`;

leftEl.addEventListener("click", function({ target }) {
  if (target !== this) if (target.tagName === "DIV") {
    var liEl = target.parentNode;
    var classAttr = liEl.getAttribute("class");
    console.clear();
    console.log(1, this.scrollHeight);
    if (classAttr === "unfolded") {
      liEl.removeAttribute("class");
    } else if (classAttr !== "leaf") {
      liEl.setAttribute("class", "unfolded");
    }
    console.log(2, this.scrollHeight);
    if (this.scrollHeight > this.offsetHeight) {
      this.style.overflowY = "scroll";
    } else {
      this.style.overflowY = "hidden";
    }
  }
});

leftEl.addEventListener("mouseover", function({ target }) {
  if (target !== this) if (target.tagName === "DIV") {
    target.setAttribute("class", "highlighted");
    rightEl.textContent = target.textContent;
  }
});

leftEl.addEventListener("mouseout", function({ target }) {
  if (target !== this) if (target.tagName === "DIV") {
    target.removeAttribute("class");
  }
});

leftEl.innerHTML = "<ul>" + (
  tree.split("\n").slice(0, -1)
  // string to nested objects
. reduce(function (stack, line) {
    var i = line.search(/[^ ]/);
    var depth = i / 2;
    if (depth + 1 > stack.length) {
      var [tree] = stack.slice(-1);
      tree = tree.children.slice(-1)[0];
      tree.children = [];
      stack.push(tree);
    } else {
      stack = stack.slice(0, depth + 1);
      var [tree] = stack.slice(-1);
    }
    tree.children.push(
      { name : line.slice(i) }
    );
    return stack;
  }, [{ children : [] }])[0]
  // nested objects to HTML
. children.reduce(function nodeToHtml (
    [html, depth], { name, children }
  ) {
    children = !children ? "" : "<ul>" + (
      children.reduce(nodeToHtml, ["", depth + 1])[0]
    ) + "</ul>";
    return [html + (
      "<li" + (children ? "" : ' class="leaf"') + ">"
    +   `<div style="padding-left:${.5 + depth}em">${name}</div>`
    +   children
    + "</li>"
    ), depth];
  }, ["", 0])[0]
) + "</ul>";
```

```css
#grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / auto 1fr;
}

#grid > div:first-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background: yellow;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

#grid > div:last-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  background: cyan;
  padding: .25em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

li div {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 10px solid lime;
}

li div.highlighted {
  background: cyan;
}

li div::before {
  content: "▸\a0\a0";
}

li.unfolded > div::before {
  content: "▾\a0\a0";
}

li.leaf div::before {
  visibility: hidden;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

li.unfolded > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div>
    <!-- Example -- >
    <ul>
      <li class="leaf">
        <div class="highlighted">node /1</div>
      </li>
      <li class="unfolded">
        <div>node /2</div>
        <ul>
          <li class="leaf">
            <div>node /2/1</div>
          </li>
          <li class="leaf">
            <div>node /2/2</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- -->
  </div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Sadly, this fix is ​​not always accurate. Indeed, I found that sometimes, although `scrollHeight` - `offsetHeight` = 1, there is no handle in the scrollbar. In other words, the scrollbar appears but behaves like content height ≤ container height (yes, wtf).

The computed floating point values reveal that 0 < content height - container height < 1. Based on this observation, I have tried to reproduce the bug, but I failed. In desperation, I decided to hide the scrollbar in this case, and it worked (phew!).

```
19 | leftEl.addEventListener("click", function({ target }) {
20 |   if (target !== this) if (target.tagName === "DIV") {
   …
28 |     var style = getComputedStyle(this);
29 |     var height = parseFloat(style.height);
30 |     if (this.scrollHeight - height < 1) {
31 |       this.style.overflowY = "hidden";
32 |     } else {
33 |       this.style.overflowY = "scroll";
34 |     }
35 |   }
36 | });
```

I'm not fully happy with this solution, but it is good enough as it does not rely on the task queue anymore. However, I'm still wondering if there is a pure CSS or HTML fix.

The question remains open, I will move the big check mark to the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a issue with the div arround the p tags.
Adding:

```
1: wrap.style.width = "0px"
```

to the JavaScript code inside the case 2, and then:

```
2: wrap.style.width = ""
```

to the case 0, solves the border on state 4. However its still not shown nicely on state 2.

Adding:

```
3: overflow-y: scroll;
```

to #grid div:first-child and:

```
4: overflow: hidden;
```

to #grid allows the horizontal scrollbar to be hidden although this results in the vertical scrollbar being visible on the first state.
Then adding:

```
5: gridEl.style.overflow = "visible"
```

to the JS makes it visible again.

Adding:

```
6: #wrap {
      display: none;
   }
```

To the CSS eliminates the initial scrollbar. Then adding:

```
7: wrap.style.display = "block"
```

to the JS lets it be shown after that.
I have added the above change to your code below:

```js
var i = 0;
var infoEl = document.getElementById("info");
var gridEl = document.getElementById("grid");
var wrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
var [leftEl, rightEl] = gridEl.children;
rightEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
  infoEl.textContent = (
    "STATE #" + (((i + 1) % 4) + 1)
  );
  /* change 5 */
  gridEl.style.overflow = "visible"
  /* change 7 */
  wrap.style.display = "block"
  
  switch (i++ % 4) {
    case 0:
      leftEl.setAttribute("class", "show-children");
      /* change 2 */
      wrap.style.width = ""
      
      break;
    case 2:
      /* change 1 */
      wrap.style.width = "0px"
      
      leftEl.removeAttribute("class");
      break;
    default: // = case 1 and case 3
      rightEl.innerHTML = "UPDATE #" + (i / 2);
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
#grid {
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / auto minmax(0, 1fr);
  background: pink;
  /* change 4 */
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

#grid div:first-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  background: yellow;
  /* change 3 */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
}

#grid div:last-child {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  background: cyan;
  user-select : none;
}

#grid p {
  margin: 1em 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 10px solid red;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#grid .show-children p {
  display: block;
}

/* change 6 */
#wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p id="info">STATE #1</p>
<div id="grid">
  <div id="wrap">
    <p>A B C D E F G</p>
    <p>A B C D E F G</p>
    <p>A B C D E F G</p>
    <p>A B C D E F G</p>
    <p>A B C D E F G</p>
    <p>A B C D E F G</p>
    <p>A B C D E F G</p>
    <p>A B C D E F G</p>
    <p>A B C D E F G</p>
  </div>
  <div>CLICK ME (SLOWLY)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your fix seems to work for this particular code snippet, but the actual source code is a bit different, so I've updated my question to make it more specific.

Comment: Thanks. Your paved the way to an [interesting solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75846535/11446880).